# Room and Livedata false positive notification

Tags: java, android-room, android-livedata

I am observing to following query from a chat screen activity:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM messages where conversationId = :conversationId order by id desc")
LiveData<List<Message>> getMessagesByConversationId(long conversationId);
```

So if a message comes to this conversation id my observers will be notified. But the problem is i detected my observers are notifiying even a message comes to another conversation id. I guess this is a big problem for huge tables because there are too many rows and my query will run everytime when a message arrives to another conversation. I think this is inefficent.

How can i do this process more efficent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Room** only knows that the table has been modified but doesn’t know why and what has changed. Therefore, after the re-query, the result of the query is emitted by the `LiveData` or `Flowable`.

Since **Room** doesn’t hold any data in memory and can’t assume that objects have `equals()`, it can’t tell whether this is the same data or not.
You need to make sure that your `DAO` filters emissions and only reacts to distinct objects.

If the observable query is implemented using `Flowables`, use [Flowable#distinctUntilChanged](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#distinctUntilChanged).

```
@Dao
abstract class UserDao : BaseDao<User>() {

    /**
    * Get a user by id.
    * @return the user from the table with a specific id.
    */

    @Query(“SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userid = :id”)
    protected abstract fun getUserById(id: String): Flowable<User>

     fun getDistinctUserById(id: String): Flowable<User> = getUserById(id)
                                  .distinctUntilChanged()

}
```

Find more implementation details here: [7 Pro-tips for Room](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/7-pro-tips-for-room-fbadea4bfbd1#5e38)

```
distinctUntilChanged()
```

Returns a Flowable that emits all items emitted by the source Publisher that are distinct from their immediate predecessors based on `Object.equals(Object)` comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logic that is used in pagination behalf on retrieving all the data..

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM messages where conversationId = :conversationId order by id desc limit  :numberOfData :pageNumber")
LiveData<List<Message>> getMessagesByConversationId(long conversationId,long numberOfData,long pageNum);
```

and in getMessagesByConversationId

you can use

```
int totalNumberOfRows=select count(*) from messages where conversationId = :conversationId ;(logic to get the number of data in query) 

pageNumber=totalNumberOfRows-(numberOfData *(pageNum-1));
```

you will get minimum data much faster ..

Happy Coding